# need help condensing nested if statements in C

Tags: c

hello I've finally got a working version of this code with all the right responses but it still doesn't look very good and I know it's kinda shit. What I'm trying to do is make certain operations only available if a variable is within a certain range. I've seen this done with if statements that look like

```
if(x > 0 || x < 10)
```

or

```
if(x > 0 && x < 10)
```

but whenever I implement those, it doesn't give me an error message, but instead loops the prompt forever or doesn't seem to discriminate at all? The same thing happens when I try and use a do/while loop with those quantifiers. So you can see I've had to nest a bunch of if loops checking for each quantifier individually. Bad code. So is there a way to make it suck less? thx

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>  

void fortune1(void);
void fortune2(void);

int main (void)
{
    
    int count;
    int num1;
    int num2; 
    char color;

    
    //get color
    printf("Color?\n");
    scanf("%s", &color);
    count = strlen(&color);                               
    
    if(count % 2 == 0)                                     //if even, load screen1. screen1 values = 1,2,3,4
    { 
        printf("Pick a number from 1 to 4.\n");
        scanf("%d", &num1);                                //remember, must be in range 1-4. program this later.
        
            if(num1 < 5)
            {
                if(num1 > 0)
                {
                    if(num1 % 2 == 0) 
                    {
                        fortune1(); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fortune2();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Invalid\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Invalid\n");
            }
    }
    else                                                 //if odd, load screen 2. screen2 values = 5,6,7,8
                                                         //get new value
    {
        printf("Pick a number from 5 to 8.\n");
        scanf("%d", &num1);                                //remember, must be in range 1-4. program this later.
        
            if(num1 < 9)
            {
                if(num1 > 4)
                {
                    if(num1 % 2 == 0) 
                    {
                        fortune1(); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fortune2();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Invalid\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Invalid\n");
            }
    }
}


// fortune1 function
void fortune1(void)
{         
        int fort;

    printf("Pick a number from 1 to 4.\n");
    scanf("%d", &fort);
            
        if(fort == 1){
            printf("fortune1\n");
        }
        else if(fort == 2){
            printf("fortune2\n");
        }
        else if(fort == 3){
            printf("fortune3\n");
        }
        else if(fort == 4){
            printf("fortune4\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Invalid\n");
        }
        
}

    
// fortune2 function

void fortune2(void)
{     
    int tune;

    printf("Pick a number from 5 to 8.\n");
    scanf("%d", &tune);
            
        if(tune == 5){
            printf("fortune5\n");
        }
        else if(tune == 6){
            printf("fortune6\n");
        }
        else if(tune == 7){
            printf("fortune7\n");
        }
        else if(tune == 8){
            printf("fortune8\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Invalid\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: Your main code doesn't include neither `if(x > 0 || x < 10)` nor `if(x > 0 && x < 10)`. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). By the way, `char color; scanf("%s", &color);` is dangerous. You must allocate an array of characters.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have never seen:

```
if(x > 0 || x < 10)
```

because it's always `true`

BTW, all of these:

```
if(num1 < 5)
{
      if(num1 > 0)
      {
           if(num1 % 2 == 0) 
           {
               fortune1(); 
           }
           else
           {
               fortune2();
           }
       }
       else
       {
           printf("Invalid\n");
       }
   }
   else
   {
       printf("Invalid\n");
   }
```

Can be rewritten with:

```
if(num1 < 5 && num1 > 0){
   if(num1 % 2 == 0)fortune1(); 
   else fortune2();
} else printf("Invalid\n");
```

and this

```
    if(tune == 5){
        printf("fortune5\n");
    }
    else if(tune == 6){
        printf("fortune6\n");
    }
    else if(tune == 7){
        printf("fortune7\n");
    }
    else if(tune == 8){
        printf("fortune8\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Invalid\n");
    }
```

Can be rewritten using `switch`:

```
switch(tune){
     case 5: 
          // do something
          break;
     case 6: 
          // do something
          break;
     case 7: 
          // do something
          break;
     case 8: 
          // do something
          break;
     default:
          printf("Invalid\n");
}
```